# Guava HashMultimap update equal value

Tags: guava

I have a hashmultimap, the current behavior of this data structure is whenever I try to insert a value that already exists, it does not insert, however I would like a different behavior: if the object I want to insert as value is equals, I want to update this value.

Comment: Why can't you just use `java.util.HashMap` then?

Comment: Can you go into detail about what you're trying to do?  e.g. why are the value objects considered equal even though they are different?

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is the result of `HashMultimap` using a standard `HashSet` for its value collection.  The contract of [`Set#add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)) is:

> If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged

However, the contract of multimap does not require this.  If you create a `Collection` implementation that has the update behaviour you desire, you can use [Multimaps#newMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#newMultimap(java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Supplier)) to create a multimap using that backing collection type.

I would caution though that this requirement seems suspect...the fact that you're trying to update the value objects while they are being used in a `Set` is somewhat smelly. It could be that what you really want is something like `Map<CompositeKey<CurrentKey, CurrentValue>, State>`.  Then the update behavior simply becomes a `put`.